# Inner product? Yes or no?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I define an "inner product" on $H_0^2(U)$ where $U \subset R^n$ is bounded open set:

$$\langle u,v\rangle = \int_U \Delta u \Delta v dx.$$

I need this when trying to find a weak solution for my PDE problem: 
$$\Delta^2 u= f \textrm{ on } U, \quad u=\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0 \textrm{ on } \partial U.$$

I have problems with condition $\langle u,u\rangle=0$ if and only if $u=0$.

If we take into account $u=\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0 $ on $\partial U$, i suppose that this condition holds on space $V:=\{ u \in H^2(U), u=\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0 $ on $\partial U \}$ but i am not sure.

Also in my opinion $V \neq H_0^2(U) = \{ u \in H^2(U), u=0 $ on $\partial U \}$ and this is trubling me. Any contribution appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is an inner product when $\Omega$ is conneted. Note that the condition $\langle u,u\rangle=0$ implies that $u$ is weakly harmonic. Using Weyl's lemma of [these lecture notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~lms/pdebk/lec4.pdf), $u$ can be represented by a $C^\infty(\Omega)$ function. Then conclude as [in this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99030/a-property-of-weakly-harmonic-functions).

Comment: But my problem states that $U$ is open and bounded with smooth boundary. There is no assumption that $U$ is connected.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to see [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354032/using-lax-milgram-to-find-a-weak-solution-in-an-intersection-of-sobolev-spaces#comment762932_354032)
Or
 [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349278/pde-weak-solution-problem)
Containing discussions about weak solution of your problem.